# Posting to wall from iOS to facebook shows blank image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

Im trying to post a wall message with an image from the iOS app using this code:

```
- (void) putOnFacebookWall:(UIImage *) screenShot{

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSString *filePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"temp.png"];

    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(screenShot) writeToFile:filePath options:NSAtomicWrite error:nil];

    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"ironman.jpg"]);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed"];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

    //
    [request setPostValue:imageData forKey:@"picture"];

    [request setPostValue:@"http://apps.facebook.com/mobie-hair-wizz" forKey:@"link"];

    [request setPostValue:@"test" forKey:@"message"];

    [request setPostValue:[defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] forKey:@"access_token"];
    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(sendToPhotosFinished:)];

    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];

}
```

what I get is this:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/z5nzm271zkadq4j/wall.png?m

What is the reason that the image is not displayed?

I also get a positive response in the iOS code from FB, saying that the upload was successful.

Comment: Is this code meant to upload the screenshot or some photo of Iron Man? The value of `imageData` is set to the PNG data of `[UIImage imageNamed:@"ironman.jpg"]`. If this is what you're trying to upload, does this image exist?

Comment: thx for help but I solved it, I will post the code right now in my own answer

Comment: will you please post the code which you had solved.I am facing the same problem.